# Magento data migration: Customer custom attributes

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, data-migration-tool

I want to migrate customer custom attributes from Magento1.9.3.2(community) to Magento 2.3.0 (Enterprise). I have tried with default attributes its works fine. Then I am trying with customer custom attribute like a telephone but it is not working with migration.

Please give me some idea, where I map custom attributes and how I can add that in the XML file.
Please check below attachment.
[image]

Comment: you have which type error showing between migration

Comment: not showing any error. Any separate log have generated for that please tell me I will check and post here

Comment: now I am getting "Record structure does not match provided Data" this error.

Comment: yes i know that about error you can error message or screenshot add in your question

Comment: I have updated a question, please check

Comment: @RakeshDonga your answer was right. Thanks man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below solutions, with file name,

```
magento2/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-commerce/1.9.3.2/map.xml
```

you have to keep below tag inside `<destination><document_rules>`

```
    <ignore>
            <document>inventory_geoname</document>
    </ignore>
```

Comment: Not working. I think issue not with inventory_geoname, maybe the issue in customer attribute

Comment: you have not correctly added because i have many migration done so i have tell you mate

Comment: but still, my custom attribute for a customer is not migrated. Now I have added it correctly.  Is I need to add my custom attribute for a customer in any config file.

Comment: you are change in config.xml file map.xml.dist to map.xml after map.xml file add above code

Comment: yes, it's already done. Rakesh, to migrate custom attributes for the customer, are we need to map that attribute in any XML file?

Comment: Sure, Thank a lot Rakesh. Appreciate your efforts.